# Replacing a character by another character in a string in android?

Tags: java, android, replace, special-characters

Simply i want to replace a character with another in android.. 
My code:

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String str = et.getText().toString();
str.replace(' ','_');
et.setText(str);
System.out.println(str);
```

But here the "space" is not replaced by "underscore".. I also tried other character too..

please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code:

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String str = et.getText().toString();
str = str.replace(' ', '_');
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 56):

Strings are immutable in Java - `replace` doesn't change the existing string, it returns a new one. You want:

```
str = str.replace(' ','_');
```

(This is definitely a duplicate, but I don't have enough time right now to find an appropriate one...)

Answer (score 6):

String is immutable and you cannot change it. So, you need to do this:

```
str = str.replace(' ','_');
```